# How changing the variables into the function name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to clone the variable name? You can see below (look name **a1**)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    name = "a1"; // This "NAME" is a1

})

function name() { // USING "NAME"
        $("#test" + name).keydown(function(a) { // USING "NAME"
                13 == a.keyCode && load + name(); // USING "NAME"
        })
}
function load + name() {
        $("#blue" + name).show(); // USING "NAME"
        localStorage. + name; // USING "NAME"
}
```

So I want to reduce the size of javasript. Because, if I do not do it. So will a lot of commands like that (though only differ in name only). Any **a1, a2, a3, a4 .......... z8, z9**

I think there is no other way than copying and pasting. And replace each name. But I hope, there are other ways

```
function a1() {
        $("#testa1").keydown(function(a) { 
                13 == a.keyCode && loada1();
        })
}
function a2() {
        $("#testa2").keydown(function(a) { 
                13 == a.keyCode && loada2(); 
        })
}

    // TO .................................

function z9() {
        $("#testz9").keydown(function(a) { 
                13 == a.keyCode && loadz9(); 
        })
}
```

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Show your actual code, we can suggest solution

Comment: you should consider a different structure, with functions with a paramter for the different use.

Comment: A **really bad way** would be something like - `window["load" + name]()`.
Instead you should try making use of parameters in functions and make them generic.

Comment: A loop, a single function and a passed argument should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

#### Proper solution

Consider moving these values to `data-*` attributes on the input themselves. A structure like this:

```
<input type="text" data-name="a1">

$('input').keydown(function(a) { 
     13 == a.keyCode && load( $(this).attr('data-name') ); 
});
 
function load(name){
    $("#blue" + name).show(); // USING "NAME"
    localStorage.name; // USING "NAME"
}
```

A side note, watch out for `localStorage. + name`; I don't get what you're trying to achieve on that line.

---

Now, for the **dangerous** practice. Please, do NOT follow this, it's a possible aspect for the language, but it doesn't mean you should use it.

use `window[<functionName>]` to define a dynamic function in global scope.

```
var name = 'a1';
window[name] = function(){
    $("#testz9").keydown(function(a) { 
           13 == a.keyCode && window['load'+name](); 
    });
}; 
window['load'+name] = function(){
    $("#blue" + name).show(); // USING "NAME"
    localStorage. + name; // USING "NAME"
};
```

Comment: Leaving this on SO is dangerous as other readers could see it as a solution to their problem, spreading the anti-pattern and causing more damages than help. It is better to educate OP about how to solve the situation he is facing.

Comment: I know it's tempting to show you mad hax0r skills but please swap the solutions, showing the proper one first :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a parameter for the functions.

Advantage: only one function and reusable for more multiple elements.

```
function go(n) {
    $("#test" + n).keydown(function(a) {
        13 == a.keyCode && load(n);
    });
}

function load(n) {
    $("#blue" + n).show();
    localStorage[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have many functions doing almost the same job, it is a very clear indicator that you should have only one functions with parameters. This way if you want to change something in your function, you don't need to change dozens but just one.

```
function register(name) {
  $("#test" + name).keydown(function(a) { 
    13 == a.keyCode && load(name);
  })
}

function load(name) {
  $("#blue" + name).show();
  localStorage.getItem(name); // do something with it
}

// Register all these methods
["a1", "a2", ..., "z9"].forEach(register);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, assign a common class to all elements that you want to attach a `keydown` handler. Say `loading`. That allows you to install all the handlers at one and then look at the ID to determine the name.

When you know the name, call a single, shared `load()` function that gets the name as argument.

```
$('.loading').keydown(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    name name = id.substring(4); // strip 'test'
    load(name);
});

function load(name) {
    $("#blue" + name).show(); // USING "NAME"
    localStorage[name]; // USING "NAME"
}
```

Remarks:

- Instead of relying on the length/prefix, use a character like `_` or `-` and split the name at the position of that character to find the suffix.
- You should also look at HTML5 data attributes to specify the key to use in `load()`.